# Flask app deployment can't import my package

Tags: python, flask

I'm following this link [Deploy to Production](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/tutorial/deploy/)

After having deployed the whl file on the server, then installed it through pip, if I run `pip list` the package is present. But in a python console I can't import it.
Is there any reason ?

Following this tutorial [packaging-projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/), is it mandatory to upload the package as explained in the "Uploading the distribution archives" section ?

Thanks

Comment: are you using a virtual environment? If that's the case, are you running the `pip list` and the `import` in the same environment?

Comment: Did you create a virtual environment for your flask deployment? If so, are you running the `pip list` command from the same environment?

Comment: Yes I use a venv . `which python` returns me the correct venv

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link in my 1st post to create a package and I discovered the tree files was not correct. So I rearranged it and now it's fine